# Shrinking down a grid to use as tab-like navigation?

Tags: usability, navigation, tabs

I am trying to design a navigation system for users researching entities. This is what you see when you arrive at a page for a particular entity - basic info, plus a whole load of different expandable research options, such as history, people etc, each with a small preview of the information available.

[image]

My question is what to do when the user clicks on one of these research options. My overall goals are:

1. to show the user more information quickly
2. to keep the various options in place, so the user can still switch between them
3. to keep the top-level info in place, so that the user can sensibly deep-link to any of the options for the entity, e.g. `/entity/history`.

The way I have done this is to collapse the different options, and treat them as tabs.

[image]

But the problem is that having tabs in a multi-level grid seems a bit strange. (Also, when there are 5 or 7 tabs, as there sometimes will be, it'll be even stranger.)

Do you think this works okay, or can anyone suggest a better way to do things? Maybe a carousel instead of a grid?

Answer (score 1):

Could you consider moving the tabs to the side? That would be less confusing than the "multi-level grid" and allow the number of tabs to grow as needed.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f713D8.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The issue with this is that I'd like to show a preview of all the different options on the landing page.

Comment: @cakehoover Must both pages have the same layout? I assumed the landing page would still show the insights but then use a tab layout for switching between sections. Or is it, in fact, one page?

Comment: It's a single page application, so it is in effect the same page. I'd quite like to keep some consistency between the two pages, in any case.